# Possible to run x3 tests simultaneously on one node using the same Browser?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

Possible to run x3 tests simultaneously on one node using the same browser?

1. My test involves adding x1 to the basket.
2. Is this even possible when cookies are involved because the same browser is being used therefore wouldnt the following scenrio listed below take place and therefore cause the test to fail?
3. Tes1 executes first adds item to the basket, test2 then executes and adds an item to the basket but now has two items in the basket because test1 added the first item.
4. Both test cases fail.

Answer (score 0):

This will be valid only in the case of Internet explorer which uses a shared memory. For chrome and Firefox it shouldn't be a problem because both the browser's rely on user data folder (chrome ) and profile (Firefox) to manage cookies. And Selenium ensures that the tests get a clean profile or user data folder